# ViewPagerAdapter Tab Title Translations Android library neokree/materialtabs

Tags: java, android, class, material-design, charsequence

In my App, I am using the materialtabs library by neokree.
I want my App to support multiple languages, so I want the Tab titles to support translations. But i dont get it to work!
The ViewPagerAdapter.java has this method "Charsequence getPageTitle(int position)"
so i made a switch(position).
But now, for example:

```
case 0:
    return R.string.title1;
```

doesnt work because the R.string.title1 returns int. But i cant use getString or getResources because it is a helper class.
And I cant use context because it sais "class cannot extend multiple classes".
Any solutions?

Here is my code:

ViewPagerAdapter.java:

```
    package jdev.voicerecorder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Locale;

 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public Context c;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }







    public Fragment getItem(int num){

        Log.d("tag", "num " + num);
        switch (num){
            case 0:
                return new Record();
            case 1:
                return new ShowList();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){



        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return R.string.title1;
            case 1:
                return R.string.title2;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Mainactivity.java (I called it RecordingActivity.java):

```
    package jdev.voicerecorder;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.File;

import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;


public class RecordingActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener{

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        File folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                +File.separator
                +"/Recordings");
        boolean success=true;
        if (!folder.exists()){
            success=folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (success){

        }else {

        }


        tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);



        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.addTab(
                    tabHost.newTab()
                            .setText(pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this)
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recording, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab materialTab) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(materialTab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab materialTab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab materialTab) {

    }
}
```

And strings.xml:

```
   <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Recorder</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string name="recordTab">Record</string>
    <string name="recordsTab">All records</string>
    <string name="allrecordsTab">ALL RECORDS</string>
    <string name="editexttitle">Filename</string>
    <string name="savingpath">"Recording saved</string>
    <string name="exText">Recording</string>
    <string name="buttonSave">Save</string>
    <string name="buttonRecord">Record</string>
    <string name="Recording">Recording</string>
    <string name="deleted">File removed</string>
    <string name="title1">Record</string>
    <string name="title2">All Files</string>
    <string name="bla">Bla</string>
</resources>
```

And the error log is

```
    Error:(51, 32) error: incompatible types
required: CharSequence
found:    int
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the ID, use getResources().getString(...)

For example:

```
return getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
```

Comment: That doesnt work. I cant usw getresources in the helper activity

Comment: Either pass a context into the ViewPagerAdapter or set it up as a class in the activity class

Comment: Actually, looking at your code, you could replace pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i) and do it in your activity

Answer (score 0):

try this in your "ViewPagerAdapter.java:":

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
public Context c;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context){
    super(fm);
    c = context; /////
}

public Fragment getItem(int num){

    Log.d("tag", "num " + num);
    switch (num){
        case 0:
            return new Record();
        case 1:
            return new ShowList();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){

    String settitle1 = c.getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
    String settitle2 = c.getResources().getString(R.string.title2);


    String tabtitles[] = new String[] { settitle1, settitle2 };

    return tabtitles[position];
}
```

}

and in your RecordingActivity replace this :

```
pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

by

```
pagerAdapter.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: Hey, a few years later and I am wondering what the hell I was thinking asking this question... Right, so I wanted to clean up, as this question probably didn't help anyone, no upvotes have been given & it's completely irrelevant on this forum anyway. That's why I'm asking you if you'd be so kind as to self-delete your answer (:/) in order for that to work (one answer max, and the other guy seems fairly inactive). Have a nice day!